# DBMS_SCHEDULER failure

Tags: oracle, plsql, scheduler

I execute this code:

```
CURSOR JOB_RUNS_cur (P_JOB_NAME IN VARCHAR2)
  IS
     SELECT COUNT ( * )
       FROM ALL_SCHEDULER_RUNNING_JOBS
      WHERE OWNER = 'BATCH'
        AND JOB_NAME = P_JOB_NAME;

   DerAktuelleJob   := 'BATCH_SST_AENDERUNGEN_JOB';

     OPEN JOB_RUNS_cur (DerAktuelleJob);

     FETCH JOB_RUNS_cur INTO Anzahl;

     CLOSE JOB_RUNS_cur;

     -- Bei Anzahl=0 läuft der Job aktuell nicht und kann gestartet werden
     IF Anzahl = 0 THEN
        **DBMS_SCHEDULER.ENABLE ('BATCH.BATCH_SST_AENDERUNGEN');**
        DBMS_SCHEDULER.ENABLE ('BATCH.' || DerAktuelleJob);
     END IF;
```

and I sometimes I get this
error at `DBMS_SCHEDULER.ENABLE ('BATCH.BATCH_SST_AENDERUNGEN');`:

```
Error in sql query: ORA-01013: User requested abort of current operation
> ORA-00604: Error at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-01013: User requested cancellation of the current operation
ORA-06512: in "SYS.DBMS_ISCHED", line 4790
ORA-06512: in "SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER", line 3020
```

Who can help me to analyze/resolve the problem?

Comment: Please translate the title and error into English ([SO] is an English only website).

Comment: usually ORA-01013 is a result of user interaction - typically the use of "CRTL+C". Did you issue a corresponding termination?

Comment: You don't need to declare an explicit cursor, you can just write `SELECT COUNT ( * ) INTO Anzahl
       FROM ALL_SCHEDULER_RUNNING_JOBS
      WHERE OWNER = 'BATCH'
        AND JOB_NAME = P_JOB_NAME;` What I don't understand, why do you enable a job which does not run? Do you disable the job every time it has been started or did you set `end_date` or `max_runs` attribute? When these are not set then the job remains enabled after running. As far as I know a SCHEDULER JOB cannot run more than once at a time, so your entire procedure seems to be rather pointless.

Comment: Intermittent errors are almost impossible for us to diagnose. ORA-01013 is an example of a eror which has too many possible causes. You need to talk with your DBA and ask them whether their monitoring can explain why this happens when it does.